# Misconception of confidence intervals.

Tags: statistics, confidence-interval

Let A and B be events such that $P(A)=P(B)=0.95$. I know that 
$$P(A\cup B) = P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)$$
and hence $P(A \cap B) \geq 0.9$

How can I use the information above to disprove the misconception that a 95% confidence interval for a quantity $\theta$ implies then there is a 95% chance that $\theta$ lies in the interval?

Comment: I think the misconception is founded not in the figure $0.95$ but rather that $\theta$ is not probabilistic and therefore not associated with any chance. We cannot claim there is $95\%$ chance as there exists no such probability. It either **is** or **is not** in the interval. Instead we must state that we have $95\%$ **confidence** that the interval contains the true value $\theta$.

Comment: The sample average which generates the interval is the random quantity, not $\theta$